# How does getDefaultProvider work in ethers.js?

Tags: etherscan, infura, web3-providers, ethers.js

From the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html):

> This creates a FallbackProvider backed by multiple backends (INFURA and Etherscan).
>   This is the recommended method of connecting to the Ethereum network
>   if you are not running your own Ethereum node.

As far as I know, both Infura and Etherscan require API keys. Did [Richard Moore](https://github.com/ricmoo) convince them to make their tools a public good when used via ethers.js?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I was also wondering recently when I was getting `429 Too Many Requests` responses from the default provider. Looking at the source code there are default API keys hardcoded in the source code (see [etherscan-provider.ts#L87](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/4a8d579dcaf026d0c232e20176605d34cba4767d/packages/providers/src.ts/etherscan-provider.ts#L87) and [infura-provider.ts#17](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/4a8d579dcaf026d0c232e20176605d34cba4767d/packages/providers/src.ts/infura-provider.ts#L17)).

It is possible that Richard has some additional arrangements with Etherscan/Infura to allow higher rate limits on those keys, but as I noticed, it *is* possible to hit the rate limits.